# Please guide me, to configure qt on lubuntu 13.10

Tags: qt5

1. I had downloaded Lubuntu(version of ubuntu)13.10..
2. Downloaded `gccc(4.8.2)/qt5..qt`. Installed as it was `.run` file. But could not compile a single app on it, even a simplest one(though qt has its own sdk).
3. qt was asking default compiler. It was asking for ppa (Personal Package Archive).
4. Downloaded `gcc-4.8-doc_4.8.2-5ubuntu4~ppa2_all.deb`,a ppa to install, while I run `ppa:<gcc*.deb>/ppa` on terminal, then get error. Please any, provide me guidance to proceed

Comment: Please edit and format your question - Download what from where?  Give an example how you are compiling. Downloaded a ppa? what & where? What error?

Comment: Try to install dev packages? Example: libqt4-dev

Answer (score 1):

**Install .run files**

```
sudo sh [FILENAME].run
```

Or

```
sudo ./[FILENAME].run
```

**Install .deb files**

```
sudo dpkg -i [FILENAME].deb
```

Or

Install Gdebi with

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

Then right click on the file and select `open with Gebi package installer`.

I have posted some guides [here](http://allfreeubuntu.blogspot.com/2013/11/how-to-install-software-from-other.html) and [here](http://allfreeubuntu.blogspot.com/2013/11/how-to-run-jar-or-run-file-in-ubuntu.html)